# From the list of 3-tuples, how can I select tuples which contain one for more nines?

Tags: list-manipulation

From the list

```
Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 3]
```

how can I select exactly those 3-tuples that contain one for more nines?

This is the result I want:

> ```
> {{1, 1, 9}, {1, 2, 9}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 9, 1}  ... {9, 9, 4}, {9, 9, 9}}
> ```

Comment: Help > Wolfram Docuentation, enter "select" (with or without quotes). First hit is to `Select`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list=Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 3] ;
Cases[{___,9,___}]@list
```

> {{1, 1, 9}, {1, 2, 9}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 9, 1}, {1, 9, 2}, {1,
>      9, 3}, {1, 9, 4}, {1, 9, 9},
>   {2, 1, 9}, {2, 2, 9}, {2, 3, 9}, {2, 
>     4, 9}, {2, 9, 1}, {2, 9, 2}, {2, 9, 3}, {2, 9, 4}, {2, 9, 9},
>   {3, 1,
>      9}, {3, 2, 9}, {3, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 9, 1}, {3, 9, 2}, {3, 9, 
>     3}, {3, 9, 4}, {3, 9, 9},
>   {4, 1, 9}, {4, 2, 9}, {4, 3, 9}, {4, 4,  9}, {4, 9, 1}, {4, 9, 2}, {4, 9, 3}, {4, 9, 4}, {4, 9, 9},
>    {9, 1,  1},   {9, 1, 2}, {9, 1, 3}, {9, 1, 4}, {9, 1, 9}, {9, 2, 1}, {9, 2, 
>     2}, {9, 2, 3}, {9, 2, 4}, {9, 2, 9},
>    {9, 3, 1}, {9, 3, 2}, {9, 3, 
>     3}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 3, 9}, {9, 4, 1}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 4, 3}, {9, 4, 
>     4}, {9, 4, 9},
>    {9, 9, 1}, {9, 9, 2}, {9, 9, 3}, {9, 9, 4}, {9, 9, 
>     9}}

Answer (score 6):

try

```
Select[Tuples[{1,2,3,4,9},3],MemberQ@9]
```

> {{1,1,9},{1,2,9},{1,3,9},{1,4,9},{1,9,1},{1,9,2},{1,9,3},{1,9,4},{1,9,9},{2,1,9},{2,2,9},{2,3,9},{2,4,9},{2,9,1},{2,9,2},{2,9,3},{2,9,4},{2,9,9},{3,1,9},{3,2,9},{3,3,9},{3,4,9},{3,9,1},{3,9,2},{3,9,3},{3,9,4},{3,9,9},{4,1,9},{4,2,9},{4,3,9},{4,4,9},{4,9,1},{4,9,2},{4,9,3},{4,9,4},{4,9,9},{9,1,1},{9,1,2},{9,1,3},{9,1,4},{9,1,9},{9,2,1},{9,2,2},{9,2,3},{9,2,4},{9,2,9},{9,3,1},{9,3,2},{9,3,3},{9,3,4},{9,3,9},{9,4,1},{9,4,2},{9,4,3},{9,4,4},{9,4,9},{9,9,1},{9,9,2},{9,9,3},{9,9,4},{9,9,9}}

Comment: This can even be shortened to `Select[Tuples[{1,2,3,4,9},3], MemberQ[9]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
L = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 3];

Pick[L, Total /@ UnitBox[L - 9], 1 | 2 | 3]
```

Or

```
Pick[L, Total /@ UnitStep[L - 8], 1 | 2 | 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst // Pick[#, Times@@@(# /. 9-> 0), 0] &
```

and

```
Pick[lst,Times@@@(lst/. 9-> 0),0]==
Pick[lst, MemberQ[#,9]&/@lst]
```